# How to get a DateTime from total amount of seconds?

Tags: c#, datetime

Let's say I have

> int seconds = 43200;

(amount of seconds from the beginning of the current day, 00:00:00) and I want to get related `DateTime` representation ("12:00:00"). Is there any c# utility function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need the [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), then you can get the `DateTime` in this way:

```
TimeSpan timeOfDay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds( seconds );
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add( timeOfDay );
```

Comment: Thank you! I should ask this in my previous question you answered. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 10):

It is not a `DateTime` representation, it looks like a `TimeSpan` representation to me instead.

For this, you can use [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds.aspx) method like;

```
int seconds = 43200;
var ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
```

[image]

If you *really* need to add this to generate current day midday, you can use [`DateTime.Today` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) and add this to that.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add(ts);
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate it directly:

```
int seconds = 43200;
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Today.AddSeconds(seconds);
```